# Chocolatey no Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, variáveis-de-ambiente

Eu estou tentanto usar os comandos nativos do windows Powershell para instalar os pacotes do Chocolatey porém quando uso um comando como `Get-ChocolateyVersion` recebo a mensagem de erro:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\chocolatey\0.0.48\Chocolatey.psm1:1597 caractere:9
>   +         Throw "Chocolatey Software not found

Porém o arquivo existe e está instalado no caminho correto exceto que minha máquina é em pt-br logo a pasta é "Arquivos de Programas" e  não Program Files.
Porém já tentei mudar a variável de ambiente pra apontar para a pasta correta mas não adianta nada assim que executa o comando ele cai no mesmo erro.

Eu tentei:

```
$env:ProgramFiles = "C:\Arquivos de Programas"

Set-Variable -Name ProgramFiles -Value "C:\Arquivos de Programas"
```

Em ambos os casos se eu fizer `echo $env:ProgramFiles` ele imprime o valor que eu coloquei mas se eu executar o comando `Get-ChocolateyVersion` ele aponta novamente pra o caminho errado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirme que existe uma variável de sistema chamada `ChocolateyInstall` e que o seu valor é o caminho correcto para a pasta onde o *chocolatey* está instalado.

Exemplo:

```
$env:ChocolateyInstall = "%ProgramData%\chocolatey"
```

Comment: fiz no meu ambiente aqui mais nao retornou nada, como eu sei que se encontra install?